# CakePHP array items form submitted - how to recover each item

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I have 8 form fields in CakePHP 2, and I need to get the values after the form being submitted to the another action.

How can it be done?

Here is my form :

```
echo $this->Form->input('Instructions.instruction', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->input('Instructions.instruction', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->input('Instructions.instruction', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->input('Instructions.instruction', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->input('Instructions.instruction', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->input('Instructions.instruction', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->input('Instructions.instruction', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->input('Instructions.instruction', array('rows' => '3'));
```

In the action I would receive but this way only the last  received :

```
'Instructions' => array( // Until 8
    // 'instruction one.',
    // 'instruction two.',
    $data['Instructions']['instruction']
),
```

Comment: Make ```Instructions.instruction``` to ```Instructions.0.instruction``` or ```Instructions.[].instruction``` or ```Instructions.instruction.[]```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerically index your inputs so that you can differentiate.  This could be done through looping.

View code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    echo $this->Form->input("Instructions.{$i}.instruction", array('rows' => '3'));
}
```

Controller:

```
foreach ($this->request->data['Instructions'] as $instruction) {
    // do what you will
}
```